# From Game Maker to Python

Tags: python, 2d, game-maker

I use Game Maker for creating simple (and not simple) 2D games for Windows.

I really love it. It's easy to use, it's powerfull and it allows me to create games very fast.

But now I know about Python. Python is my new love.

I would like to create games using Python now. I would like to have something like Game Maker but with Python inside.

Googling "python game engines", I've found these ones:

**1) PyGame**

2) Cocos2D

3) Blender

4) Python-Ogre

Maybe I'm wrong, but I've found that:

1) PyGame is not more powerfull (for Windows) than Game Maker. And the last realese was in 2009.

2) Cocos2D is usually used for creating mobile games with C# and Java. It's not more powerfull than Game Maker too.

3) Blender is 3D engine. Don't think it is a easier way to create 2D games than Game Maker.

4) Python-Ogre -- same as Blender.

So, what would you recommend me?

Comment: "More powerful"? How do you quantify that? This question is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Same functionality. Nothing totally different. It's not a fact. May be  I'm wrong. I just watched some lessons and read some parts of documentation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is also [Kivy](http://kivy.org/#home), a crossplatform Python framework

Answer (score 3):

[You missed one](http://www.renpy.org/). And it's PyGame underneath, if you need something a bit lower level.

Answer (score 0):

What about a combination of the two?
[gmpython](http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=454433&hl=gmpython)